# Edit profile - PDO

Tags: php, pdo, edit

I'm trying to include in my script the page to change the details of the user profile. I did it this way, in the class user.php I included this:

```
// Update profile
    public function update($email,$gender,$location) {
        try {
        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('UPDATE members SET email = ?, gender = ?, location = ? WHERE memberID = ? ');
        $stmt->execute(array($email,$gender,$location,$_SESSION['memberID']));
        return $stmt->fetch();
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
        }
    }
```

While, for example, the page account.php I did it this way:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// new data
$email = $_POST['email'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
    $id = $_SESSION['memberID'];

// query
if ($user->update($email,$gender,$location,$id)); {
    redirect('account.php');
}
}
```

And,

```
<form action="account.php" method="POST">
Email<br>
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['email'] ?>" /><br>
Gender<br>
<input type="text" name="gender" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['gender'] ?>" /><br>
Location<br>
<input type="text" name="location" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['location'] ?>" /><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Use a connection in PDO from how it is understood, however, I have tried many options but always with poor results.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. What is your question?

Comment: Hello, I asked for help. The code I wrote is not working properly, it does not update the data. What about it? Could you help me?

Comment: its an update statement, `->fetch()` doesn't make sense at all, use `->rowCount() > 0` instead

Comment: did you enable exception mode in PDO? by default it doesn't use exceptions. Plus, `->fetch()` on an `update` query? That makes no sense.

Comment: Done, unfortunately still nothing ..

Answer (score 0):

in your class the method:
public function update($email,$gender,$location);

It's not accepting the $id like parameter.

So the solution can be:
a. Use the id of the object and not use the $_SESSION['memberID'].

```
public function update($email,$gender,$location) {
    try {
    $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('UPDATE members SET email = ?, gender = ?, location = ? WHERE memberID = ?');
    $stmt->execute(array($email,$gender,$location,$this->id);
    return true;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
    }
    return false;
}
```

b. Receive the id in the function and use it. If this is the case it's better to use this like a static method.

```
public static function update($email,$gender,$location,$id) {
    try {
    $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('UPDATE members SET email = ?, gender = ?, location = ? WHERE memberID = ?');
    $stmt->execute(array($email,$gender,$location,$id);
    return true;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
    }
    return false;
}
```

So call it, depending of the strategy used. Also don't do echo in the method of the class model, just asign to a error message property and let the caller do the output.

Hope it helps.